# YAML SSH Private Key variable is truncated when passed between stages

Tags: azure-devops, ansible, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have this Azure ADO yaml pipeline with 2 stages. Stage RetrieveSSHKeys retrieves ssh priavte keys from Cyberark, stores it in a variable and that variable is referenced in the 2nd AnsibleRole stage. The problem I have is, in the Retrieve stage the content of variable is printed fully, that is the ssh-key is full. But when it's referenced in the AnsibleRole, it only takes the first line "ansiblesshkey - -----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----". So the ansible fails with "nLoad key "/tmp/temp-sshkey": invalid format" error.

```
# J2C Ansible post vm build Pipeline
# 
variables:
  - group: blueline-providers

parameters:
  - name: module
    type: string
    values:
      - ADHOC_tasks
      - PATCH
    displayName: The SAP SID to deploy.

  - name: AnsibleRoles
    displayName: Configure LVM, NFS, SAP Requirements
    type: boolean
    default: false


trigger: none

pool:
  name: "sap-Pool"

stages:

  - stage: RetrieveSSHkeys
    displayName: Retrieve SSH Private Keys
    jobs:
      - job: FetchKeys
        displayName: Fetch ssh keys from Cyberark vault
        pool:
          name: "sap-WinPool"
        steps:
          - powershell: |


              $UserID = $env:vault_user_ansible
              $pw = $env:VAULT_PASSWORD_ANSIBLE


              $secureString = ConvertTo-SecureString $pw -AsPlainText -Force
              $url = "xxx"

              $credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential("$UserID", $secureString)
              $res = (Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $url -Credential $credential)


              $secretKey = $res.Content

              $null = Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=retrievedsshkey;isOutput=true;NoEcho=true]$secretKey"
              # $null = Write-Output ("##vso[task.setvariable variable=retrievedsshkey;issecret=true;isOutput=true;NoEcho=true]{0}" -f $secretKey)
              
              Set-Variable -Name retrievedsshkey -Value $secretKey -Scope Script
              Write-Host "key is :$retrievedsshkey"
            name: printkeys
            workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/${{ parameters.module }}/ansible
            env:
              VAULT_PASSWORD_ANSIBLE: $(vault_password_ansible)
                
  - stage: AnsibleRoles
    displayName: Configure LVM, NFS, SAP Requirements
    dependsOn: RetrieveSSHkeys
    condition: |
      and (
        succeeded('RetrieveSSHKeys'),
        ${{ parameters.AnsibleRoles }}
        ) 
    jobs:
      - job: AnsibleRoles
        displayName: Configure LVM, NFS, SAP Requirements
        variables:
          ansiblesshkey: $[ stageDependencies.RetrieveSSHkeys.FetchKeys.outputs['printkeys.retrievedsshkey'] ]
        steps:
        - bash: |
            # source ~ansible/ansible2.9/bin/activate
            echo "ansiblesshkey - $(ansiblesshkey)"
            echo "$(ansiblesshkey)" > /tmp/temp-sshkey
            chmod 600 /tmp/temp-sshkey
            ansible-playbook -i inventory.yml --private-key=/tmp/temp-sshkey playbook.yml
            # rm -f /tmp/temp-sshkey
          workingDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/${{ parameters.module }}/ansible
          displayName: Configure LVM, NFS, SAP Requirements
          env:
            sapinst_pass_env: $(sapinst_encrypted_pass)
```

I tried encoding with encodeing base64 in powershell and decoding it in ansibleRole, still it was incomplete.

Fyi, I cannot run both the stage in same pipeline because the Invoke-RestMethod doesn't work from Linux OS agent machine because it's on different DOMAIN and it alwasy throws up the authorization issue. So, I had to run the stages in 2 different with RetrieveSSHkeys on Windows OS (where my login id is in same domain as Windows OS) and use the key in AnsibleRole which can only run from Linux OS agent. So, I cannot store the variable in a file and pass it.

Comment: Hi @Pravin, multiple lines variable in DevOps is not supported yet, as a workaround, you can publish the artifact and download it in next stage to use, i have added details in the reply below. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

multiple lines variable in DevOps is not supported yet, please check the existing [user voice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/multiple-lines-variable-in-build-and-release/365667) for the details.

You can put the ssh key content in a file, publish it as an artifact and download it in your next stage.

```
$keycontent | Set-Content temp-sshkey
```

My complete testing code sample:

```
pool:
  vmImage: Windows-latest

steps:
- task: DownloadSecureFile@1
  name: sshkey
  inputs:
    secureFile: 'id_rsa'

- powershell: |
   #prepare the keycontent
   $keycontent = Get-Content -Path $(sshkey.secureFilePath)

   # set the key value to a file which can be used in next job
   $keycontent | Set-Content temp-sshkey

- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
  inputs:
    targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/s/temp-sshkey'
    artifact: 'sshkeyfile'
    publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

The artifact file content:
[image]